# Is it possible to SELECT FOR UPDATE on DBContext?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using one timestamp field of my table to avoid the same data do be returned to different users performing the same query.

To achieve that I would like to update the records that matches my select statement using only one query. In postgres I believe it would be possible by using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement, but is it possible on `DbContext`? I'm trying to avoid multiple DB calls here.

Right now the select statement I'm using looks like that:

```
using (var context = new InventoryContext())
{
    var numbers = await (from a in context.Phones
                       where a.City.Equals(city, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                             a.Type.Equals(type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                       select a).ToListAsync();
}
```

How do I change that so a.updateTimeStamp is updated for all entries on that query?

---

UPDATE:

This will not solve my problem (because concurency can still happen) but to update the data selected on the statement above one would call:

```
foreach (var n in numbers)
{
    n.reservationTime = requestTime;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want _to avoid the same data do be returned to different users performing the same query_. If user A reads some records, should user B wait until user A is done? (And what is "done" in this context?). The common usage of a timestamp field is optimistic concurrency, which is all but locking.

Comment: If user A reads some records I want those records to be in a "reserved" state until a certain time passes (that explains the reason for updating the timestamp). When user B performs the query I will then check for each record if an amount of time (let's say 30 minutes) has elapse before last query was performed. If 30 minutes has passed, than the record can be retuned and I will update timestamp again. Otherwise the record will not be returned.

Comment: As mipe34 said it is not possible with one instruction. I will create a storage procedure to achieve that. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with one SQL satement,

the FOR UPDATE statement you mentioned only lock rows

> the FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be
>   locked as though for update. This prevents them from being modified or
>   deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That
>   is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT FOR
>   UPDATE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction
>   ends

[reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

If you want to use the plain SQL on dbContext you can do this for queries without results:

```
string myUpdateSQL = @"UPDATE Table SET Table.col1 = other_table.col1, 
                       Table.col2 = other_table.col2 FROM Table 
                       INNER JOIN other_table ON Table.id = other_table.id";
using (var context = new InventoryContext())
{
     context.ExecuteStoreCommand(myUpdateSQL);
}
```

or this for queries returning results:

```
string sql = "select * from Chapter3.Student where Degree = @Major";
var args = new DbParameter[] { new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "Major", Value = "Masters" } };
var students = context.ExecuteStoreQuery(sql, args);
```

But the SQL code will be dependent on your database engine.

Comment: That UPDATE command would only alter the values on the table. I also need to get the selected values back.

Comment: You cannot do it with one SQL satement, the FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT FOR UPDATE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends